# Calcular dois tempos em uma variável no batch

Tags: cmd, batch

É possível calcular a diferença entre dois tempos com o batch e utilizar a resposta como uma variável dentro do comando? O comando "time" te permite fazer os cálculos entre tempo inicial e final.

```
set STARTTIME=%TIME%
set ENDTIME=%TIME%
set /A DURATION=%ENDTIME%-%STARTTIME%
```

A variável da resposta (DURATION) volta como hora:minuto:segundo:milissegundo, tem como eu comparar (com o comando if) essa variável (DURATION) com um tempo pré-definido por mim dentro da própria programação? Ou fazer algo parecido. Exemplo:

```
if %DURATION% LSS "00:00:01:00" echo Texto.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código que você está utilizando é esse:

```
@echo off
rem Inicio do procedimento.
set STARTTIME=%TIME%

rem Coloque o procedimento que deseja medir o tempo.
pause

rem Fim do procedimento.
set ENDTIME=%TIME%

set /A STARTTIME=(1%STARTTIME:~0,2%-100)*360000 + (1%STARTTIME:~3,2%-100)*6000 + (1%STARTTIME:~6,2%-100)*100 + (1%STARTTIME:~9,2%-100)
set /A ENDTIME=(1%ENDTIME:~0,2%-100)*360000 + (1%ENDTIME:~3,2%-100)*6000 + (1%ENDTIME:~6,2%-100)*100 + (1%ENDTIME:~9,2%-100)
set /A DURATION=%ENDTIME%-%STARTTIME%

if %ENDTIME% LSS %STARTTIME% set set /A DURATION=%STARTTIME%-%ENDTIME%

set /A DURATIONH=%DURATION% / 360000
set /A DURATIONM=(%DURATION% - %DURATIONH%*360000) / 6000
set /A DURATIONS=(%DURATION% - %DURATIONH%*360000 - %DURATIONM%*6000) / 100
set /A DURATIONHS=(%DURATION% - %DURATIONH%*360000 - %DURATIONM%*6000 - %DURATIONS%*100)

if %DURATIONH% LSS 10 set DURATIONH=0%DURATIONH%
if %DURATIONM% LSS 10 set DURATIONM=0%DURATIONM%
if %DURATIONS% LSS 10 set DURATIONS=0%DURATIONS%
if %DURATIONHS% LSS 10 set DURATIONHS=0%DURATIONHS%

echo Tempo do procedimento: %DURATIONH%:%DURATIONM%:%DURATIONS%

pause > nul
```

A variável `%DURATION%` armazena o tempo em centésimos de segundo, então para verificar se demorou menos que um minuto deve fazer a seguinte verificação:

```
if %DURATION% LSS 6000 (
  echo Durou menos que um minuto.
) else (
  echo Durou um minuto ou mais.
)
pause > nul
```

> 1 segundo = 100 centésimos de segundo. 1 minuto = 6000 centésimos de segundo.

Comment: Deu extremamente certo! Muito obrigado

Comment: muito obrigado!